# std::async is blocking the process exit if the thread is created from a dll?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

**Scenario:**

I have a console application (`consoleApp`) in which i use an exported function (`exported_func`) from another dll. In that function, i have started a new infinite thread. Here is the code -

```
EXPERIMENTAL_API int exported_func(void)
{
    auto f = []() {
        while (true)
        {
            cout << "H";
            this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
        }
        return 1;
    };

    async_res.value = async(launch::async, f);
    return 1;
}
```

Now, from the `main()` function i have called this function and after that i started an infinite loop in the main function. Here is the code -

```
int main()
{
    exported_func();

    while (true)
    {
        cout << "L";
        this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Problem:**

The problem is that, if i want to close my console application by clicking the close button of the console,  it takes 10 seconds to close the application.

And more, if i create a process (for the consoleApp.exe) using `CreateChildProcess`, then that process cant be terminated using `ExitProcess`.

But if i create the thread (async) from the main function(from consoleApp) then it closes immediately and can be terminated using `ExitProcess`.

Can anyone please explain whats happening here?

**Note:** I am using Visual Studio 17 and hence visual c++ v141 build tools.

Comment: What's `async_res.value`?

Comment: `async_res` is a struct and `future<int> value` is a member of it.

Comment: A global variable?

Comment: Yeah, right. Its a global variable.

Comment: And where are you storing the future in the "create thread from main function" case?

Comment: It might be taking long because DrWatson is collecting dump information. Run it under windbg.

Comment: @T.C. same, at global scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both clicking the close button and calling `ExitProcess` result in... a call to `ExitProcess`.

Part of what `ExitProcess` does is call the DLL entry point function for each loaded DLL with `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`.

Part of what VC++ runtime's DLL entry point (`_DllMainCRTStartup`) does when it receives a `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` is calling destructors for the DLL's global variables.

The destructor of a `std::future` returned by `std::async` blocks until the shared state becomes ready - which it never does, because 1) your function doesn't return and 2) `ExitProcess` forcibly terminated the thread running the function anyway.

Global objects in the EXE [are handled differently](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160930-00/?p=94425), and, at least for more recent versions of the runtime library, their destructors aren't called when `ExitProcess` is called.

Comment: Thanks! This explains most of it. But i am not quite sure why it exit after 10 seconds if i close using the close button of the console. It should hang, right?

Comment: @RasheduzzamanSourov The close button causes the OS to send a `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` to your program; the default handler for that calls `ExitProcess`. There's a time limit on how long the handler are allowed to run; Windows simply terminates the process forcibly if the handler times out.